# O nome "CreatedAtAction" não existe no contexto atual

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou seguindo o roteiro de aprendizagem [Exercício – implementar operações CRUD](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/training/modules/build-web-api-aspnet-core/8-exercise-implement-crud), porém ao tentar realizar:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Pizza pizza)
{            
    PizzaService.Add(pizza);
    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Create), new { id = pizza.Id }, pizza);
}
```

Estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem no console:

```
C:\dev\ContosoPizza\Controllers\PizzaController.cs(35,20): error CS0103: O nome "CreatedAtAction" não existe no contexto atual [C:\dev\ContosoPizza\ContosoPizza.csproj]
```

Já verifiquei o sdk usado:

```
6.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

Desinstalei, instalei novamente e reiniciei o computador.
Só não testei em outro computador por não possuir outro.
Busquei por este erro no google, mas não encontrei nada semelhante.

Estou seguindo exatamente o script do link mencionado. Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver?

Não estou obtendo sucesso ao tentar usar CreatedAtAction.

Comment: já verificou se tem os usings corretos? https://docs.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.createdataction?view=aspnetcore-6.0  essa class está no namespace `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` e precisa do respectivo package

Comment: Olá @RicardoPontual, sim, verifiquei isso, está correto.
Acredito ser alguma coisa no windows, rodei o projeto no wsl2 com ubuntu e funcionou. 
Acho que só formatando a máquina pra quem sabe resolver.

Comment: formatar a máquina pra rodar um projeto? isso é meio exagerado :)
tenta usar outros métodos para saber se é mesmo problema do package, por exemplo o `Created`

Comment: Meu receio é começar a dar problema em outros métodos.

Answer (score -1):

Opa! é porque no início da sua classe você tem que colocar a herança exemplo:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    public class nomeclasse: ControllerBase  
    {
       [HttpPost]
       public IActionResult Create(Pizza pizza)
       {            
          PizzaService.Add(pizza);
          return CreatedAtAction(nameof(Create), new { id = pizza.Id }, pizza);
       }
    }
```

coloque : ControllerBase  depois da classe em seguida coloque o
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc; no topo da classe assim irá funcionar.

Comment: Pior que não era, a ide já põe o using